# I have an ArrayList of fragments, and I'm having trouble deleting some of the fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return mListOfImagePanel.get(i);


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mListOfImagePanel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        doOnce();
        return mListOfImagePanelNames.get(position);
    }

}

}
```

This is the method I use to delete Fragments

```
private void deleteImagePanelFromDrawerLayout(int whichPanel){




    mListOfImagePanel.remove(whichPanel); // This is the ArrayList of fragment
    mListOfImagePanelNames.remove(whichPanel); // Don't care about this one
    mImagePanelSaveDatas.remove(whichPanel); // Don't care about this one



    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // PagerAdapter

    mFlip.setOffscreenPageLimit(mListOfImagePanel.size()); //ViewPager



}
```

The problem is, using that method nothing much seems to happen, there was no OnDestroy call on the fragment that I had choosen to destroy.

The only way that worked so far was the getItemPosition trick, but I cannot use that since that destroys all the fragment and recreate them, and since my Fragments have dynamic content it's not efficient to delete everything and re-create.

So is there a way to specifically to remove a specific fragment from a ArrayList of fragments.. And update the adapter efficiently?